# listings breaklines and escapeinside vs marginnote

Tags: listings, marginnote

Consider the MWE below. When I edit manuscripts I often tend to use the `fixme` package and its `marginnote` layout for notes to myself or the editor. In the latest project, I had to comment inside a listings construction. I my MWE I've boiled it down to having `breaklines` active and adding a long comment inside an escape to LaTeX in the listing.

Here are some observations

1. why does the size of `breakindent` affect the marginnote?
2. what exactly is the width of the marginnote, it does not seem to break corerctly
3. if one replace `\marginnote` by `\marginpar` then everything work correctly. So which document resetting is `\marginnote` missing?
4. one also get the correct breaks if one use `\marginnote{\parbox...}

Any comments on item 1–4?

BTW: I use the `marginote` layout over the `marginpar` one as the `marginnote` can be used everywhere!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{listings}
\setlength\marginparwidth{3cm}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  breaklines=true,
  escapeinside=YY,
%  breakindent=0pt,
}
\lstnewenvironment{TEST}[1][]{
  \lstset{style=mystyle,#1}
}{}
\newcommand\test[1]{\marginnote{#1}}

\begin{document}

% all is suppose to be written on one long line
\begin{TEST}
test Y\test{this is a long note that just keeps on going forever and ever and ever and ever and ever and ever}Y test test test test test test test test test test test
\end{TEST}


\end{document}
```

Sniplet of the output I get:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is outdated. If can be fixed by updating at least package `marginnote`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\newcommand\test[1]{{\everypar{}\marginnote{#1}}}
```

Comment: Should we ask the marginnote maintainer to add this to the code? Seems relevant now that marginpar seems to do so (haven't checked)

Comment: @daleif probably should do `\@parboxrestore` which resets a host of things, including this.

Comment: I'll have a look tomorrow and will write the maintainer